# How to call multiple routes sequentially without messing with body

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel

I have something like the following:

```
.from("direct:start")
    .to("direct:a")
    .to("direct:b")
    .to("direct:c");
```

The issue I have is `direct:a` modifies the body and then passes that modified body to b and c.  I want a, b, and c to all get the same body.  I was able to achieve this by doing `.multicast()`:

```
.from("direct:start")
    .multicast()
    .to("direct:a",
        "direct:b",
        "direct:c");
```

However, it appears the `.to(...)` blocks are not executing in sequential order anymore (even though I am not specifying `.parallelProcessing()`) and also the multicast is messing up my tx policy.  I cannot find anything that exactly fits this need.  A wireTap would achieve this I think, but that is async and I need synchronous and sequential.  I have even tried brute force saving the body to a property against the exchange and then restoring it and that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [enrich](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/enrich-eip.html) for this:

```
from("direct:start")
    .enrich("direct:a", AggregationStrategies.useOriginal(true))
    .enrich("direct:b", AggregationStrategies.useOriginal(true))
    .enrich("direct:c", AggregationStrategies.useOriginal(true));
```

The `true` argument there means that exceptions thrown by your child routes will be propagated to the main route. If you do not want that, just pass `false` or omit the argument altogether.

Comment: Thank You!  Enrich did solve my issue with the body being altered.  Will need to doublecheck tx policy

Answer (score 0):

---

You Should use the [Wire Tap](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.16.x/eips/wireTap-eip.html):

```java
from("direct:start")
    .wireTap("direct:a")
    .wireTap("direct:b")
    .wireTap("direct:c");
```

Comment: WireTap does not work as it is async